# Fixed layout for admin section

Tags: admin, css, wp-enqueue-style

I would like to customize the layout of the admin section of WordPress.

The thing is, whatever the layout I create, I'm very dependent of the default "fluid" layout of the admin. By fluid, I mean: when I resize the browser window, things tend to reorganize themselves in the admin section (in order to optimize space) and while it's a nice feature with the default look and feel of the admin section, it's a real pain in the neck when you try to create your own custom layout.

Can someone tell me which css attributes of the admin need to be changed and what attributes parameters would disable that overall fluid behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still to be confirmed but so far so good:
What I did is open all the minified css related to the admin section and deleted theses parts

```
@media only screen and (max-width:xxx px){...}
```

whenever I found one.

It seems to work and doesn't mess with anything else, as far as I know.
Of course, this only makes sense if you intend to re-layout the admin from scratch.

Comment: Be careful with a change like this. If you (or any future developer) upgrades the WP install, it will overwrite the changes you've made. Try loading your own css file on the admin pages you're creating using wp_enqueue_script(), then using CSS cascading rules to write stronger rules than the original styles.

Comment: I know. I have a css above the others but it's hard to overwrite these specific rules as they embed too many attributes. Too many of them to be investigated 1 by 1 and redefined in a new stylesheet (I tried and gave up after 2 hours). Changing the core files took me 2 minutes. As I'm not creating a reusable template or blog and as I always deactivate updates for each website, I should be fine. Plus, I keep a log with all the changes I made in the core files. I really try to keep them as few as possible but several hours of work VS 2 minutes top for a single case scenario, I made my choice.